# Export Design to PDF feature from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, u-sql

I wrote an U-SQL script in Visual Studio and it gives you the possibility to show a graph of it. The problem is that this graph is big... I would like to export it to PDF. Is that possible from within VS?

Here is a screen grab of what the graph looks like:
[image: SQL graph preview]

Comment: And the image here shows you got what you wanted. Well done.

Comment: I really appreciate your humor :). But I used the capture tool from Windows 10 to show what I want to export... My Design is generate by Visual Studio and it's a big graph. So i want to find a way to export it.

Comment: I slightly edited your question for clarity. It sounds like there should be a valid answer, even if it is only "there is no such feature in VS".

Comment: Azure Data Lake team here. Currently we don't have plan to support exporting data flow diagram as PDF. Is there any issue in VS that causes you cannot navigate the graph smoothly?